# Registrar frequência de alunos no Banco de Dados

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

possuo um sistema de gestão escolar, onde, viso adicionar uma opção dos professores adicionarem a frequência do aluno. Estou pensando em criar uma transação, onde, cada professor acessa, a página que terá: Um campo para o professor informar o CPF ou matricula, ao clicar em OK, listar em um select as turmas, que o professor está locado. Ao clicar na turma listar todos os alunos cadastrados nesta turma (nesta tabela junto com os registros dos alunos criar campos de entrada e saída, observação e data). Por fim terá um botão de registrar frequência para submeter os dados ao Banco de Dados.

O que você acha desta regra de negócio? É viável, para não dar problema no futuro!